# Charles de Gaulle Layover 4 hours 35 minutes

Tags: transit, paris, cdg

I have a 4hour 30 minutes layover in CDG and I land in terminal 2E and my next flight is also in 2E. However, I really want to visit the Starbucks in terminal 2D thus, I was wondering if it was possible for me to transfer to terminal 2D to just buy something from Starbucks. I read that there is also one at terminal 2E but because it's only in the gate M area (and I believe my flight will be on the gate K area.)

Thus, is it possible for me to go there to get something from Starbucks? (it's a present and I really need it.)

Comment: by the way, I am coming from and going to both a non-Schengen country.

Comment: You can wander around an awful lot airside at CDG T2. I'd imagine you can get there. Have you looked at maps on the CDG website?

Comment: @CMaster I did look but I couldn't clearly get the map that's why I am asking here .....

Comment: Starbucks should be banned as purveyor of overpriced, overroasted, addictive products. :)

Comment: Where did the answer to this Q go? Seemed perfectly good to me...

Comment: @CMaster really...where did it go...

Answer (score 3):

Hi I went through CDG recently and my boarding pass was checked for final destination by airport stuff before they allowed me to take the tunnel between terminals 2F and 2E.

I would say you are only allowed on your departure terminal.

Also according to http://easycdg.com/passenger-information/connecting-flight-connections-paris-cdg-airport/transfer-terminal-2e/

It takes 45 minutes to go from 2E to 2D and you need to pass through security so even if they allow you on 2D you’ll spend huge amount of time walking and passing the security check.

Please note due to recent events security is tightened so there are document and boarding pass checks at every opportunity and they are more strict than usual so they take even more time.